# Angular 5 route path not recognized

Tags: angular, routes

I am wrapping my head about this simple use case, but I can't figure it out.

I have the following routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'app', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'app', component: DssComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'app'},
];
```

In my app module:

```
import {routes} from '@app/app-routing';
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
         CoreModule,
         SharedModule,
         DssModule,             
         RouterModule,
         RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})
        ],
        bootstrap: [
            AppComponent
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

My CoreModule looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        AuthenticationService,
        CanActivateAuthGuard
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

My SharedModule looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        LoginComponent
    ],

})
export class SharedModule {}
```

My DssModule looks like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DssComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        DssComponent
    ]
})
export class DssModule {}
```

After `ng serve`, I can't seem to match "/login".

When I type `/login`, url goes to `http://localhost:4200/login/app`.

I do not get this, see trace info, it seems it only matches the slash (`/`):

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/"}
core.js:3675 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') } )
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/app", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') } )
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ResolveStart
platform-browser.js:367 ResolveStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') } )
platform-browser.js:367 ResolveStart {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ResolveEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ResolveEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') } )
platform-browser.js:367 ResolveEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
dss.component.ts:19 dsscomponent!
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd {id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/app"}
```

It does not matter what I type, I get redirected to 'xxx/app'

**SOLUTION:**
I do not know why, but the solution to this problem was to remove my 'node_modules' folder and do a "npm install" again. That worked. Creepy stuff.

Comment: Do you have have two router-outlets? What if you type xxx/login

Comment: I have one router-outlet in my application-component.html: 
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
The path 'xxx/login' is not reachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fist posted Code lookd fine, there's something else in your environment that is causing this issue.

The real question may boil down to, did you place the `<router-outlet>` in the main component, did you declare or import all used components in that module

It's very common to split app.module.ts with app-routing.module.ts to keep a neater module file.

See below for example of your first post working with the information you've provided.

[Reproduced on stackblitz as is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwiihq)

Comment: I have placed the router-outlet in the app-component.html in the app module
The reproduced code is not module based, as you also can see, I imported all modules in the app module

Comment: I recommend to try to simplify your problem to the minimum requirement to create routing, as listed in the example above, then slowly work your way up to see when you lose it. Like declare components directly in app.module.ts, keep a simple html for each component and app.component.ts.  It's hard to help without seeing the rest of your html and code, and it seems like you're importing things multiple times

Comment: Well, it had to do somethinig with my node_modules' folder. I deleted all the node modules, run 'npm install' again and it worked! I found out when I copied the files in a different folder and wanted to refactor to one app module to make it simple as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I definitely encourage splitting module with a routing module when files get big, it's good practice to keep files short. The rest of the modules you create in lower levels should use forChild(<routes>), only the main one uses forRoot()

Answer (score -3):

You need to include `RouterModule,` as well as `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})` within your imports. The `forRoot()` is for enabling child navigation

Comment: What do you mean? I use the RouterModule.forRoot not forRoots()

Comment: my bad, it was a typo, i mistyped the `s`

Comment: no problem, I still do not understand your comment anyways lol

Comment: swap ```imports: [
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})
    ],``` for ```imports: [
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})
    ],```

Comment: Ah thought so, does not work unfortunately. I still get redirected to '/login/app', viewing the XXComponent.

Comment: ah, i just realised, you dont add the routermodule in the app.module.ts file like you should do. that is probably causing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164340/discussion-between-g-mast-and-mast3rd3mon).

Comment: you need to add the components into the declarations, under appcompoennt

Comment: The LoginComponent, is declared and exported in SharedModule. The DssComponent is declared and exported in DssModule. The app module already imports both modules.